# Why probability density is equal to = $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

this is the formula used for probability density (where f(x) is the probability density function):

> $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$$

but it does not make sense to me , I will explain in details:

according to Riemann integral definition , $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 
0}\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k) \Delta x $$ , $n \rightarrow \infty \text{ as } x \rightarrow 0$

$\because$ $f(x)$ is just frequency divided by class width

$$ \therefore = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\sum_{k=1}^n {{f_k} \over \Delta x} \Delta x = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\sum_{k=1}^n {{f_k}} = \text{sum of all frequencies over the interval $[a,b[$}$$

so the integral of $f(x)$ does not give the probability of having a continuous random variable over the interval [a,b[

i am a newbie and sorry if the question sounds stupid to you and it will be very appreciated if someone could clean things up

thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Your $f$ *is* the probability density function, not the integral. (And what do you call the "probability function" ?)

Comment: @Yves Daoust if $f$ is probability density function , why do we use the integral of $f$to get the probability in the first place?

Comment: Pretty much by definition. If we say f is a density function for a certain distribution, we are saying, by definition, that it's the function who's integral over the whole space is 1 and who's integral on a specific measurable subset is the probability of that subset.

Comment: @Measureme so you are telling me , it's not a REAL integral and we just using the DEFINITION only? did i get your point?

Comment: @Measureme  because if we are really taking the integral of $f(x)$ then we should be multiplying by an infinitesimal change in $x$ which as i explained in the question , it ruined the formula

Comment: Well, it depends on what you are given. I'll tell you what I got from it. If you are given a density function, and it is told to you that it is (you could prove a function is a density function as well), you still have two cases:discrete and non descrete. With the non discrete you have what I said before: yes by definition you should have that the probability is the integral and reading all the theory behind it, it does what you want. If it is descrete you actually have that the probability is a summation by definition as well, it is easy er to check. .

Comment: So they are two separate cases, however I think I read something about the fact that you could use some notion of integral to make sure that in the descrete cases, it is correct to use the integral notation, but it is not important for basic probability theory understanding

Comment: @Measureme so let me check my comprehension , the integral of probability density function is just an ARBITRARY way to get the probability over an interval and there is not really a good INTUITION behind it, the only reason we use it is that it works and gives us what we want ?

Comment: @Measureme and it should not make sense compared to something like integral of velocity which gives position because time is a continuous  so we need the change in time to be close to zero to get the position

Comment: Not really what i wanted to say. First of all the definitions in general i think are given so that is all turns out to be intuitive. Anyways, the fact is that you are talking about a density function $f(x)$, which means that you already know that it is a density function, in other worlds you know that it satisfies the definition. and it is here that the definition enters.

Comment: For example if you are given a continuous function $f$, then you can use the definition of continuity for $f$ through the whole process that comes next, becouse you are given as an hipothesys it is continuous. Maybe i didnt get your point, if the problem isn't this.

Comment: @Measureme i get what you are saying but my main problem was that integral of $f(x)$ simplifies to sum of frequencies over the inteval [a,b[ which is not what we wanted , i wanted to know how the integral of $f(x)$ is supposed to calculate the probability over an interval OR maybe you already tried to explain but i could not get you

Comment: So for sure the density function is not arbitrary, and also not every probability has one. Simply you saing, having f(x) as a probability density, i'm assuming it is given and it is a density, so by definition we are working with the probability $P$ such that $P(A)=\int_{S} f(x) dx$ for $A$ measurable.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you are talking about descrete probability, so as i told you, you don't apply that definition, at least i was taught like this. It asctually is a sum, just as i assume you are looking for.

Comment: like if we are ltalking about the probability $P$ of a coin toss then you would say $P(A)=\sum_{x\in A}P(x)$ where $A \subseteq \Omega:=\{Head,Tail\}$

Comment: @Measureme i am not talking about discrete probability, i get that discrete probability is calculated that way but $\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k) \Delta x$ i wrote in the question above is just the formula for calculating integrals according to Riemann integral definition and has nothing to do with discrete probability

Comment: @Measureme i can give you the reference to what i am talking about so you can make sense of what i am saying : https://www.probabilisticworld.com/mean-variance-probability-distributions/ (scroll down to the part where they say : Continuous random variables revisited where they calculated  the tree height probabilty by integral of $f(x)$

Comment: Well I don't think that is a correct formula for calculating the integrals in the Riemann sense. In fact you should have some dependance between $n$ and $\Delta x$. In fact if the maximum $\Delta x_i$ goes to 0, then the partition of points choosen should have "a lot of points", in some sense $n\to +\infty$. If you go check how the Riemann integral is constructed, this becomes clear. As a conclusion you don't have a finite sum.

Comment: @Measureme ik that $n \rightarrow \infty$ when $ \Delta x$ equals 0 but still the main problem exists, it still simplifies to sum of frequencies.

Comment: @Measureme btw I have clarified your point  in the question, I know I annoyed you a lot, and sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @Measureme it would be really helpful if you tell me exactly what a "probability density" is , because I think of "probability density" as frequency/class-width and i think of the probability density curve as infinite no. of density histograms with their class-width approaching 0  and all stacked together and I think that's what's causing the whole problem.

Comment: I Think of it as a  function whose area on a measurable set gives you the probability of that set. It makes it easier in many cases to calculate the probability if you know this function. Not all of the probabilities have it, but if you are dealing with one that does, you can apply all we know about integrals to it and you are done.

Comment: Given a ranbom variable $X$ (we are talking about integrals on real numbers) a probability density function is any measurable function that satisfies: $P(X\in A)=\int_{X^{-1}(A)}dP=\int_{A}f(x)dx$ for any measurable set $A$.

Comment: @Measureme i can get it now , thanks a lot for your time and help (if you can post this as answer so i can mark it as correct , that would be great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think of it as a function whose area on a measurable set gives you the probability of that set. It makes it easier in many cases to calculate the probability if you know this function. Not all of the probabilities have it, but if you are dealing with one that does, you can apply all we know about integrals to it and you are done.